# Accessing learned words Samsung Galaxy A12 keyboard

Tags: keyboard, system, android-12, data

I share a phone with someone who's being shifty and I just need some help.
I was typing an email address into the search bar on the Samsung Galaxy A12 that we share and as I was doing so, a whole bunch of suggestions showed up on the keyboard- they were all usernames with an @ in front of them.
( @username )

I was going to write them down but the problem is that after I clicked on 2 or 3 suggestions, they stopped popping back up in the suggestion part of the keyboard.

It seems like it may have accidentally glitched or something and they weren't meant to pop up at all, but the fact that they DID means they're saved somewhere on the phone, right? The phone only has the Samsung keyboard on it- not GBoard board and the phone is not rooted.

Is there any way at all that I can access that again? Anything I can try?
Can I root the phone myself to access that data?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question, but this is significant problem with many of these keyboards nowadays, especially those that also connect to the internet.  Despite privacy "promises", it's often hard to know if private data is truly staying private.